How to Export CSV without using any Package in C# (,NET Core)?
How can you create a well structured csv file without using any packages in .NET core.
And use class Keys as Header.
    public class TestArray
    {
        public string LastName{ get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
        public string MoNumber { get; set; }
    }

I tried with the CsvHelper Package, it's work Perfectly, but I want to Export csv file without using any packages.

CsvHelper is open source package. Take a look how they did it. Obviously, it's not a practical question (for real-life scenario you would use a package). And if it is for your education - then what exactly is the question?

@Felix I want to Export Csv file without using any packages, because If I use CsvHelper then it will Overwrite some package version and I am not able to use properly. that's why I want something that is export csv file without using any packages.

public class TestArray
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string MoNumber { get; set; } 
}

public static void ExportCsv<TestArray>(List<TestArray> genericList, string filePath)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var header = "";
    var info = typeof(TestArray).GetProperties();
    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        var file = File.Create(filePath);
        file.Close();
        foreach (var prop in typeof(TestArray).GetProperties())
        {
            header += prop.Name + ",";
        }
        header = header.Substring(0, header.Length - 2);
        sb.AppendLine(header);
        TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath, true);
        sw.Write(sb.ToString());
        sw.Close();
    }
    foreach (var obj in genericList)
    {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        var line = "";
        foreach (var prop in info)
        {
            line += prop.GetValue(obj, null) + ",";
        }
        line = line.Substring(0, line.Length - 2);
        sb.AppendLine(line);
        TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath, true);
        sw.Write(sb.ToString());
        sw.Close();
    }
}

Usage:
    var arrayData = new List<TestArray>
                    {
                        new() {
                            LastName = "John", FirstName = "Deo", Age = "20", MoNumber = "123456789"
                        },
                        new() {
                            LastName = "Seno", FirstName = "Verma", Age = "10", MoNumber = "9876543210"
                        }
                    };

    string filePath = "E:\\FolderName\\fileName.csv";  // file path should be include file Name and extention

    ExportCsv(arrayData, filePath);


Downloaded File Preview

Try this:
Step 1: Create Your Data Class
You've already defined the TestArray class. However, there's a potential typo or issue with the property type for MoNumber. Assuming it's meant to be a string or something similar to represent a mobile number, I'll correct it here:
public class TestArray
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string MoNumber { get; set; }  // Assuming this should be a string.
}

Step 2: Create a Method to Write Data to CSV
Below is a method to write a list of TestArray objects to a CSV file:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public class CsvExporter
{
    public static void WriteCsv<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, string path)
    {
        Type itemType = typeof(T);
        var props = itemType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                            .Where(pi => pi.PropertyType == typeof(string) || pi.PropertyType == typeof(bool) || pi.PropertyType.IsPrimitive)
                            .ToArray();

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            // Writing header (property names)
            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", props.Select(p => p.Name)));

            // Writing data
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", props.Select(p => GetValue(p, item))));
            }
        }
    }

    private static string GetValue(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, object obj)
    {
        var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
        return value?.ToString().Replace(",", ";");  // Escape commas in data
    }
}


Step 3: Using the Method
You can now use this method to create a CSV file. Here is an example of how to use this method:
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<TestArray> list = new List<TestArray>
        {
            new TestArray { LastName = "Smith", FirstName = "John", Age = "30", MoNumber = "9876543210" },
            new TestArray { LastName = "Doe", FirstName = "Jane", Age = "25", MoNumber = "1234567890" }
        };

        CsvExporter.WriteCsv(list, "test.csv");
        Console.WriteLine("CSV file has been written.");
    }
}

Notes:

Ensure that your properties are simple types that can be converted directly to a string. If you have complex types or you need special formatting, you might need to adjust the GetValue method accordingly.
This example handles basic CSV writing scenarios. If you have requirements for special characters, multiline values, or other CSV complexities, you might need to extend the logic to handle such cases properly.


You can use Reflection to write a generic ExportCsv function:
using System.Text;

var testList = new List<TestArray>
{
    new() { LastName = "Alpha", FirstName = "Beta", Age = "123 yo", MoNumber = true },
    new() { LastName = "Gamma", FirstName = "Delta", Age = "234 \"years\" old", MoNumber = false }
};

Console.WriteLine(ExportCsv(testList));
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Junk\Junk.csv",ExportCsv(testList));
Console.WriteLine("Finished");
Console.ReadKey();

static string ExportCsv<T>(List<T> list)
{
    if (list == null) return "";
    if (list.Count == 0) return "";
    var sb = new StringBuilder();    
    foreach(var prop in list[0]!.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        sb.Append($"\"{prop.Name}\",");
    }
    sb.AppendLine();
    foreach(var item in list)
    {
        foreach (var prop in item!.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var value = prop.GetValue(item) ?? string.Empty;            
            sb.Append($"\"{value.ToString()!.Replace("\"", "\"\"")} \",");
        }
       sb.AppendLine();
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

public class TestArray
{
    public string LastName { get; set; } = "";
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = "";
    public string Age { get; set; } = "";
    public bool MoNumber { get; set; }
}

